# How to perform "mailto" and controller action both in anchor tag (or @Hmtl.ActionLink)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mailto

I want the user to send email using their local email client, and the activity should be logged in the database.
Means, I want to perform "mailto" and a controller action when user clicks on a link.

Can anyone help me to perform "mailto" and controller action both in anchor tag (or @Hmtl.ActionLink)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have the link point to an MVC action that logs the activity and then returns a `RedirectResult` to a `mailto:` URL.